# Something went wrong with jade JS inline accepting my JSON from node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I process API data in my node, then pass to JADE for html compiling.
Inside Jade I use javascript to generate map from google api.

The problem is that in jade, while in body, I can access passed data easily. But when I request it in the script. section, it does not work anymore.

Jade:

body
p #{stringedd}

## map

script.
var coord = #{stringedd};

Node:

```
stringed = { lat: 41.403931, lng: 2.191565 };
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {stringedd: JSON.stringify(stringed)});
  });
```

Paragraph (p) in Jade prints out fine, fails only in JS.
Maybe I'm requesting it wrong?

Comment: Did you try to use it like this : 

`script. var coord = stringedd;`

Had the problem once and if I remember well it solved it

Comment: Didn't work. :(